# Alternate camera is blocked during conference in Vidyo.io from mobile browser

Tags: vidyo

I am developing web application using Vidyo.io where requirement is as user will be on mobile browser(android) and user need to take snapshot from back camera during conference. I am observing that when we are starting camera it is showing black.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to perform the following:

1 - store a reference to each available camera using RegisterLocalCameraEventListener

2 - release the camera from the vidyo sdk by calling vidyoConnector.SelectLocalCamera({localCamera: null})

3 - use the android camera to perform snapshot

4 - allocate the camera back to vidyo by calling vidyoConnector.SelectLocalCamera({localCamera: whateverCameraYouWantToSelect})